# Python syntax reasoning (why not fall back for . the way django template syntax does?)

Tags: python, types, syntax, django-templates

My karate instructor is fond of saying, "a block is a lock is a throw is a blow."  What he means is this:  When we come to a technique in a form, although it might seem to look like a block, a little creativity and examination shows that it can also be seen as some kind of joint lock, or some kind of throw, or some kind of blow.

So it is with the way the django template syntax uses the dot (".") character.  It perceives it first as a dictionary lookup, but it will also treat it as a class attribute, a method, or list index - in that order.  The assumption seems to be that, one way or another, we are looking for a piece of knowledge.  Whatever means may be employed to store that knowledge, we'll treat it in such a way as to get it into the template.

Why doesn't python do the same?  If there's a case where I *might* have assigned a dictionary term spam['eggs'], but know for sure that spam has an attribute eggs, why not let me just write spam.eggs and sort it out the way django templates do?

Otherwise, I have to except an AttributeError and add three additional lines of code.

I'm particularly interested in the philosophy that drives this setup.  Is it regarded as part of strong typing?

Comment: Because Guido van Rossum didn't want to do it this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JUST MY correct OPINION's opinion is indeed correct. I can't say why Guido did it this way but I can say why I'm glad that he did.

1. I can look at code and **know right away** if some expression is accessing the 'b' key in a dict-like object `a`, the 'b' attribute on the object `a`, a method being called on or the `b` index into the sequence `a`.
2. **Python doesn't have to try all of the above options every time there is an attribute lookup**. Imagine if every time one indexed into a list, Python had to try three other options first. List intensive programs would drag. Python is slow enough!
3. It means that when I'm writing code, **I have to know what I'm doing.** I can't just toss objects around and hope that I'll get the information somewhere somehow. I have to know that I want to lookup a key, access an attribute, index a list or call a method. I like it that way because it **helps me think clearly** about the code that I'm writing. I know what the identifiers are referencing and what attributes and methods I'm expecting the object of those references to support.

Of course Guido Van Rossum might have just flipped a coin for all I know (He probably didn't) so you would have to ask him yourself if you really want to know.

As for your comment about having to surround these things with `try` blocks, it probably means that you're not writing very robust code. Generally, you want your code to expect to get some piece of information from a dict-like object, list-like object or a regular object. You should know which way it's going to do it and let anything else raise an exception.

The exception to this is that it's OK to conflate attribute access and method calls using the `property` decorator and more general descriptors. This is only good if the method doesn't take arguments.

Comment: Great answer!  I like all three of your points.  The first one seems to have a weak point, though and it's this:  If I, as a developer, *want* to write code that's easier or harder to read, there are no shortages of ways for me to do it.  In this case, I might want to opt to nix three lines despite making the code marginally more difficult to read. Your third point is very psychedelic and well put.

Comment: @Justin. You can always write unreadable code. It comes down to trade offs though. If the harder to read code is legitimately faster or more robust, than you gain something from it. The reader should at least be able to parse out, from looking at the one piece of code, what properties are required of objects for the code to run.

Comment: It's also true that a lot of idiomatic Python that newcomers think is unreadable or not explicit, e.g, `if not list_` instead of `if len(list_) == 0:` is actually perfectly readable and explicit _once you learn Python_.

Comment: or, perhaps, realize that in many cases Python is just english.  :-)  (Your example is a great case in point)

Comment: I have accepted this as the right answer because I think it gives the best and most holistic impression of the placement of this syntax element in the larger python philosophy.

Answer (score 7):

django templates and python are two, unrelated languages.  They also have different target audiences.

In django templates, the target audience is designers, who proabably don't want to learn 4 different ways of doing roughly the same thing ( a dictionary lookup ).  Thus there is a single syntax in django templates that performs the lookup in several possible ways.

python has quite a different audience.  developers actually make use of the many different ways of doing similar things, and overload each with distinct meaning.  When one fails it should *fail*, because that is what the developer means for it to do.

Comment: Also a great answer!  Your last sentence is poetry! :-)

Answer (score 1):

- The different methods of accessing
  attributes do different things. If
  you have a function foo the two lines
  of code
  `a = foo,
  a = foo()` 
  do two
  very different things. Without
  distinct syntax to reference and call
  functions there would be no way for
  python to know whether the variable
  should be a reference to foo or the
  result of running foo. The () syntax removes the ambiguity.
- Lists and dictionaries are two very different data structures. One of the things that determine which one is appropriate in a given situation is how its contents can be accessed (key Vs index). Having separate syntax for both of them reinforces the notion that these two things are not the same and neither one is *always* appropriate.

It makes sense for these distinctions to be ignored in a template language, the person writing the html doesn't care, the template language doesn't have function pointers so it knows you don't want one. Programmers who write the python that drive the template however do care about these distinctions.

Comment: (I'm mostly playing devil's advocate here) - well then why not *also* have a single "lock is a block is a throw is a blow" operator.  Keep the dot as an attribute lookup, but have spam^eggs be a general relationship follower.

Comment: My guess. Conventions would have to decide which meaning to assume when you did spam^eggs and spam^eggs is a function, they could always assume you want to run the function and return the results but what if the function takes arguments? You still would end up with lines spam.eggs or spam.eggs('scrambled') so I'm not sure what the spam^eggs syntax would really buy you, at some point you actually have to know what you are working with and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Well, take generic relations as an example.  If you have a generic relation to a few different models, and most of them have a name attribute, but a few don't, you might make a name() method that takes no arguments and derives the name through whatever logic is relevant.  Then, you can universally use spam.eggs^name.  Now, you'll need at least an if and probably a try.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the points already posted, consider this. Python uses special member variables and functions to provide metadata about the object. Both the interpreter and programmers make heavy use of these. For example, both `dict`s and `list`s have a `__len__` member function. Now, if a `dict`'s data were accessed by using the `.` operator, a potential ambiguity arises if the `dict` has a key called `__len__`. You *could* special-case these, but many objects have a `__dict__` attribute which is a mapping of member names and values. If that object happened to be a container, which also defined a `__len__` attribute, you would end up with an utter mess.

Problems like this would end up turning Python into a mishmash of special cases that the programmer would have to constantly be aware of. This would detract from the reason why many people use Python in the first place, i.e., its elegant simplicity.

Now, consider that new users often shadow built-ins (if the code in SO questions is any indication) and having something like this starts to look like a really bad idea, since it would exacerbate the problem many-fold.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the responses above, it's not practical to merge dictionary lookup and object lookup in general because of the restrictions on object members.

What if your key has whitespace? What if it's an int, or a `frozenset`, etc.? Dot notation can't account for these discrepancies, so while it's an acceptable tradeoff for a templating language, it's unacceptable for a general-purpose programming language like Python.